# ARM assembly: Dumping d1 and d5 registers

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to adapt the following code to do half scale + Y8 extraction:

https://github.com/emrainey/DVP/blob/master/libraries/public/yuv/__uyvy_half_scale_image.S

I just want to modify lines 105 and 106 and dump to pDst d1 and d5.

According to line 105 of:

https://github.com/emrainey/DVP/blob/master/libraries/public/yuv/yuv.inc

I think that d0 has u/V, d1 has Y, d4 has U/V, and d5 has Y.

I have tried various things with vst1.8 and vst2.8 but without any luck. How can I do that?

Comment: What didn't work? Normally from the look of the output image, you can tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the vst instructions. They de-interleave by 16bit which means they contain U+Y, and V+Y each.

If I'm not mistaken, you only want the luminance values, and you have to extract them from all four registers.

```
vtrn.8 d1, d0
vtrn.8 d5, d4
```

then you have the Y values in d0 and d4

Beware though. This routine then contains tons of unnecessary instructions from start to the very end.

Why don't you look at other sources? This library is quite a bad starting point for learning/modifying due to terrible instruction choices, inconsiderate register allocations, and lack of residual handling.